# JSON Extract is returning NULL values

Tags: sql, json, string, presto

I have a sample of my dataset which looks like this:

```
WITH raw_string AS (
    SELECT CAST
    (
        '{
        "1261369621021236":["It was interactive and the guy was v nice"]
        ,"4806456876149982":["Mediahub"]
        ,"501699158168566":["Yes"]
        ,"293482916246997":["Do it IRL"]
        ,"1748555938809400":["Europe, Middle East, or Africa (EMEA)"]
        ,"3019471278301443":["Storytelling for Impact"]
        ,"1051072995806230":["Yes"],"687313266038215":["28042022"]
        ,"406048341357670":["Somewhat agree"]
        ,"304353711772145":["Very satisfied"]
        }'
        AS JSON
    ) AS answers_text
)

SELECT *,
JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(answers_text, '$["1261369621021236"]') AS q1 FROM raw_string
```

Why is this returning null? I'm trying to get a value, which in this case should be: "It was interactive and the guy was v nice"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`json_extract_scalar`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/json.html#json_extract_scalar) docs:

> The value referenced by `json_path` must be a scalar (boolean, number or string):

But you have an json array which is not a scalar value, so you need to either provide path to scalar value - `'$.1261369621021236[0]'`:

```sql
-- data
WITH raw_string AS (
    SELECT json '{"1261369621021236":["It was interactive and the guy was v nice"],
    "4806456876149982":["Mediahub"]}' AS answers_text
)

-- query
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(answers_text, '$.1261369621021236[0]') AS q1 
FROM raw_string
```

Output:

| q1 |
| --- |
| It was interactive and the guy was v nice |

Or use `JSON_EXTRACT`:

```
-- query
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(answers_text, '$.1261369621021236') AS q1 
FROM raw_string
```

Output:

| q1 |
| --- |
| ["It was interactive and the guy was v nice"] |

Also there are some options using casting to different types. For example provided json can be casted to `map(varchar, array(varchar))` and values can be extracted by key and array index (note that in presto the start from 1):

```sql
SELECT cast(answers_text as map(varchar, array(varchar)))['1261369621021236'][1] AS q1 
FROM raw_string
```

Comment: Thanks Guru. I appreciate the sources you cited.

Answer (score 0):

Because answer_text is not an array but just cast as an object with attributes remove the parenthesis and try it as follows:

```
SELECT *,
JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(answers_text, '$.1261369621021236') AS q1 FROM raw_string
```

look at the following 2 samples I used to come to the above conclusion

[Source 1](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#json_extract_scalar)

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(JSON '{ "name" : "Jakob", "age" : "6" }', '$.age') AS scalar_age;
```

[Source 2](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/json.html)

```
SELECT json_extract_scalar('[1, 2, 3]', '$[2]');
```

I could not run this against presto. My only concern is if the attribute name would be confused for big integer.I also question why you have brackets around the values. It should not be necessary for normal json

Comment: Thanks Conrad for your comment. Your suggestion of removing the double quotes does not work. I read the sources you cite when solving this problem. I think the solution may be to rename the keys from those "big numbers" first into something like "question1", and they apply the above code. I think the question numbers were auto generated in an online survey.